# while the pointcut be apply to bean ctor and all get/set property methods?

Tags: spring, aop, spring-transactions

I have a Spring AOP pointcut  `execution(* someService.*(..))`.

Will this pointcut match constructor and bean get/set property methods?

THIS is not my intention, and also maybe this behaviour will hurt performance.

I just want to advise REAL service methods, such us `getUserByID` etc.

How do I exclude those methods (get/set/constructor)?

Comment: Why do you have getters, setters and constructor in service? The service should only contains operations like eg. getUser, saveUser, deleteUser.....If for some unknown reason you need them there..you should match the pointcut to the execution of needed methods. http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-example-pointcut-advisor/

Comment: @sergiu such as get reference of ibatis or hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That pointcut will match public methods in Spring AOP. So getters and setters, but not constructors.

The Spring reference for this is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). Section 8.2.3, look for "even constructors".

A clean way to only reference a group of methods is to apply the pointcut to an interface implemented by your service, instead of the service itself. This assumes your interface only contains business methods you want to advise.

Answer (score 1):

in case it's a third party library and you don't want to use a marker interface for some reason, you can always base yourself on naming conventions of the methods. For example this applies the aspect to getters only:

```
execution(* someService.get*(..))
```

this expression applies the aspect to both getters and setters:

```
execution(* someService.get*(..)) && execution(* someService.set*(..))
```